# how to convert column's enum type to integer in hql query?

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, hql

I have a entity be contain column enum Type.
definition column enum type in entity in the following:

```
@Column(name = "gender", columnDefinition = "number(3)", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
private Gender gender;
```

I create a hql query in following :

```
SELECT customer.nationalCode AS nationalCode,
       customer.firstName AS firstName,
       customer.lastName  AS lastName,
       customer.gender AS gender
FROM Customer customer
```

this query return gender of Enum Type.
but I want to get ordinal of gender instead Enum Type.
how to convert column's enum type to integer?

Comment: Why you are not converting Gender enum to Ordinal after getting the result?

Comment: reply Amit Bera,because use Transformers **setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(CustomerModel.class))**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this with a spring boot test application and the only way it works for me is to cast the enum to int in HQL:

```
SELECT customer.nationalCode AS nationalCode,
       customer.firstName AS firstName,
       customer.lastName  AS lastName,
       CAST(customer.gender AS int) AS gender
FROM Customer customer
```

The model I used is based on your example:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String nationalCode;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "gender", columnDefinition = "number(3)", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private Gender gender;

    //getters and setters
}
```

And the enum:

```
public enum Gender {
    MALE, FEMALE;
}
```

edit: this only works of course, if you persist the enum as ORDINAL in your entity (as you do now), otherwise you'll probably get a NumberFormatException or something like that.